# Slow render in tornadoweb

Tags: tornado

I have a simple search form where a user enters an id, the applications issues a request to a backend service, getting back a json string and pass it to a template by using:

```
data = get_data_from_backend()
params = {"main_data": data['main_data'], "address_data": data['address_data']}
self.render("result.html",  **params)
```

The problem is that sometimes render might take up to 20-30 seconds.
I have benchmarked it by adding an info log right before I call render and also an info log in

```
def on_finish(self):
```

What makes it a even harder to troubleshoot is the fact that timings are not always the same, even for the same input I get variable timings, between 2 and 30 seconds. Please note that params has more variables of several datatypes: lists, dicts etc and also "result.html" is somewhat complicated because it has 5-6 includes and some of those includes have other nested includes. FWIW the behaviour is not reproducible on my development environment; it happens on production only.
Any idea of what could cause this issue ? Any idea how to troubleshoot even further ?

Thanks,
George

Comment: Are you fetching the data asynchronously? Is this - `get_data_from_backend()` - a blocking or async call?

Comment: It is an asynchronous call.

Comment: If `get_data_from_backend` is asynchronous you should use `await get_data_from_backend` ( and the function where it's called should be defined as `async`).